# XAML Trigger C# Function on isFoucsed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I am having a question. I have created a RichTextBox XAML (the one that does not have the .text property since there seem to be two differen ones). Now I want to call a function from my .cs whenever the textbox is focused and anotherone when it loses focus. 
I already figured out, how to trigger an animation like so:

```
    <Style x:Key="adressBar" TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="transparent"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation  Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FFF5F5FE" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation  Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="transparent" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But I have no idea how to call a function within there.
The function basically looks like this:

```
public void doStuff(){...}
```

I do not need to parse arguments! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply attach handlers to the [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) and [`LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus.aspx) events:

In XAML:

```
<DataGrid GotFocus="DataGrid_GotFocus" LostFocus="DataGrid_LostFocus" />
```

In code behind:

```
private void DataGrid_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    doStuff();
}

private void DataGrid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    doStuff();
}
```